# Updating only non-None case class values in slick 3.0 update

Tags: scala, slick, case-class

I have a set of simple case classes, each of which have a number of properties that are Optional:

```
case class Person (name: Option[String], age: Option[Int], etc)
```

When all case class properties are provided (not-None) the slick update code works fine - I just use the case class instance in the update query.

The question is, there are many cases which any combination of properties might be None.  I don't want to write a specific update query method for each combination.

How do I use a case class in an slick update query so slick only updates the non-None property values in the table and leaves the others intact (not trying to set them to null)?

Comment: If you want to update something partially you just use "copy" method for any case class and override what you need. Not sure if it's a solution to your problem, specific example is needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update specify columns using Slick:

```
http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#updating
```

but to achieve what you want there I'd do it with two very simple DB calls:

```
val row = db.run(q.filter(_.id === id).result.head)
row.copy(name = row.name.map(newName), age = row.age.map(newAge), ...)
db.run(q.update(row))
```

note the use of `.map` to set it only if it was previously defined.